# backbone.js model.destroy nested models and objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I call [`model.destroy`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-destroy), and my model has nested backbone models **and/or** plain JS objects, does backbone take care of their destroys as well, or will I somehow have 'dangling' objects?

From the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-42) it's not immediately obvious to me. Thanks for help.

Comment: Why would any api presume to know what properties of your object to kill off when you remove that object from some collection?

Comment: You're right what I really meant was when I call `model.destroy`, not what I originally wrote (which was `collection.remove(model)`). I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Backbone will not do anything more than send a delete request to the server for that one resource.

Comment: Yeah I figured through experimentation and logically it makes sense too...I'll accept your answer to close the question!